# Output concated value from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, left-join, concatenation

I am trying to output a concated value from my query but am having some issues.

Here is my query:

```
    $result = mysql_query(
"SELECT c.company, n.nid, n.createdOn, CONCAT_WS(' ',c2.fname,c2.lname), CONCAT_WS(' ',c3.fname,c3.lname), n.urgent, n.description 
 FROM notes n 
 INNER JOIN Positions p ON FIND_IN_SET(p.id, n.forDepts) > 0
 LEFT JOIN companies c ON c.userid = n.clientId
 LEFT JOIN companies c2 ON c2.userid = n.createdBy
 LEFT JOIN companies c3 ON c3.userid = n.claimedBy
 GROUP BY n.nid
 LIMIT 0,100"
 );
```

My array is printing like so:

```
Array ( [0] => Honda of Kirkland [company] => Honda of Kirkland [1] => 1 [nid] => 1 [2] => 2009-09-28 21:33:15 [createdOn] => 2009-09-28 21:33:15 [3] => [CONCAT_WS(' ',c2.fname,c2.lname)] => [4] => [CONCAT_WS(' ',c3.fname,c3.lname)] => [5] => 0 [urgent] => 0 [6] => Milestones [description] => Milestones )
```

I am trying it like this, but it does not work:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$created_by = $row[3];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, what's your expected output?

Comment: @RUJordan He is expecting the function to work, rather than output what seems to be a literal string.

Comment: It seems like somehow, the db isn't udnerstanding that you are trying to execute a function on those lines. Is it possible that you have an ancient version of MySQL installed that didn't have those functions - in wihch case I would have assumed an error when trying instead though...

Comment: Perhaps using an as statement might help